# Adding dummies as control variables change the coefficient

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, panel-data

It has been difficult to formulate a title for this question. But here is something that is puzzling me. I have an ordinal probit model with a bunch of covariates. One of the covariates is the number of ratified human rights conventions (ranges from 0 to 7). This variable is time-varying and coded for each state in the dataset.

So let's say that this is my model: `oprobit<-porl(y~x1+x2+x3+ratification, data=mydata, Hess=TRUE, method="probit")`

The coefficient of the "ratification" variable is positively correlated with the dependent variable and significant.

Then, I insert dummies for each of the 7 ratified conventions (coded country-year).

So: `oprobit2<-porl(y~x1+x2+x3+ratification+con1+con2+con3+con4+con5+con6+con7, data=mydata, Hess=TRUE, method="probit")`

All dummies are also positively correlated with the dependent variable, however, the "ratification" variable is now negatively correlated and significant.

I know that there might be many reasons for this. However, I am sure that this is not an unusual "problem". What is it that I am observing here? Shall I keep the dummies in the model or not?

Comment: Can this be the result of Simpson's paradox?

Comment: could you include part of the data in your question?

Comment: dear @Robert it is too big i'm afraid.